# removing outliers in a dataframe in NA

Tags: r, na, outliers

I have a dataframe with several NAs. I need to find outliers and replace them with the median, but all functions I now don't work if there are missing values. I use R. Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `na.rm=TRUE` in these functions that compute statistical descriptors. Look up `complete.cases` as well.

Comment: This works well for me `lapply(mydata, function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE);x})`

Answer (score 0):

`na.rm=TRUE` works for specific functions, or else you can run `df <- na.omit(df)` if you want to remove the NA values from the dataframe entirely and not just for those specific functions.